# Websocket Chat on a normal Web Server

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, server, livechat

I want to programm a simple live chat (with a websocket). (Like that: https://socket-io-chat.now.sh/)

My problem: I only have a normal webserver where I can run php,html..
Not a Node.js server or something like that.

I also have only limited rights [I can't install things,..], because a have rented the server.

If it helps, I have a MYSQL-Database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stumbing block is likely going to be that you cannot install anything, so Websockets is probably out. You could probably use [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to achieve the same sort of result.

Whether you would still describe it as "a simple live chat" once you have finished is another matter.